# How do I customize the emails and confirmation code when signing up a user with Amazon Cognito?

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, single-page-application

I am using Amazon Cognito to manage user accounts for my website. When a user signs up, a code is emailed to the user to confirm their account.

I have two requirements:

1. I need to send a branded email with a six-digit code.
2. The user needs to enter the code into six textboxes to confirm their account (see below).

My solution is to have the front-end call the backend when signing up a user. From there I could generate the code and send it in the branded email using Amazon's SES service. I would then return a hash of the code in the response back to the client. When the user enters the code, the front-end would calculate its hash and automatically proceed to the next screen if the hashes match.

How do I confirm the account in Cognito? It appears that it needs the code that it generated - not mine. Is there a way to do this? Maybe I'm overthinking it.[image]